# Spring Webflow: How to pass a bean from a controller to a flow? (using input mapping)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mapping, javabeans, spring-webflow

I'm trying to do this on one of my flows:

```
<!-- Initial inputs -->
<input name="profileId" required="true" type="long" />
<input name="profile" required="true" type="com.myapp.model.Profile" />
```

Redundant, I know. It's just for debugging purposes

The problem here is that profile is null (com.myapp.model.Profile), throwing an exception to my flow handler due to the required attribute error.
However, profileId (long) is not null and works fine.

My question:

Is there a possibility that the type couldn't be just only a long type? ([Here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/web-flow/64141-input-a-list-of-integers-into-flow) is another related topic)

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mappingUrl", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
public String go2Flow(.... some parameters ...,
@ModelAttribute("profile") Profile profile,
ModelMap model) {

model.put("profile", profile);
model.put("profileId", profile.getId());

return "redirect:/app/myFlow";
}
```

**EDIT:**

I solved it. Since I was using @SessionAttributes on my Spring MVC Controller for the object Profile (named 'profile'), on my flow I just used the ExternalContext API to retrieve that object.

Therefore, the controller keeps the same code, but on my flow the ExternalContext API can be used like this:

```
<on-start>
    <evaluate expression="someService.serviceMethod(externalContext)" result="flowScope.outputVariable" />
</on-start>
```

and then on the service method:

```
@Override
public SomeObject serviceMethod(ExternalContext externalContext) {

     Profile profile = (Profile) externalContext.getSessionMap().get("profile");

      .....
     (method logic)
      .....
}
```

Comment: it's weird that your package name has a capital letter in it

Comment: Sorry about that. It's not the real package name. It's just an example (a bad example maybe XD).

Comment: fixed the package name. unnecessary weird stuff in a question tends to distract people.

Comment: Do not try this, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

here is what you can do:

only keep profileId and make it not required

then start you flow with

```
<decision-state id="isProfileIdSet">
    <if test="profileId != null" then="setProfile" else="errorState" />
</decision-state>

<action-state id="setProfile">/*get Profile with id and store it in flowScope */</action-state>

<end-state id="errorState"></end-state>
```

and add a `<on-start>` state or `<on-entry>` inside your first state

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already set the profileId into a flowScope on a previous version of the code. However, the main issue here is that I want to pass an entire object from a controller to the flow without any NullPointerException. I was trying something like "currentEvent.attributes.profile" but also didn't work.

Comment: why do you want to do that? why cannot your just save it and retrieve it from inside the flow?

Comment: Because it's a little part of a whole requirement. The next step is sending a HashMap to the flow from the controller. That's why I'm looking for a reference on how to do it with objects instead of doing it with a single Long type.